# Módulo turtle: comportamiento de la función .color()

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Estaba probando el módulo turtle y quiero saber bien cómo funciona la función `.color()`. 
Sé que al ejecutar el siguiente código el cursor se hace de los siguientes colores:

```
import turtle
l = turtle.Pen()
l.color(0,0,1) #Azul
l.color(0,1,1) #Celeste
l.color(1,1,1) #Blanco
l.color(0,0,0) #Negro
l.color(1,0,0) #Rojo
l.color(1,0,1) #Rosa
l.color(1,0,0) #Amarillo
"""
Todo esto lo descubrí poniendo números más o menos al azar
"""
```

Pero al intentar las siguientes combinaciones:

```
l.color(0,0,2) 
l.color(2,0,0)
```

Me da el error:

> raise TurtleGraphicsError("bad color sequence: %s" % str(color))
>   turtle.TurtleGraphicsError: bad color sequence: (2, 1, 0)

Yo creo que la función `color` es un poco limitada a estos colores que puse como ejemplo y que los únicos argumentos posibles son unos y ceros (que probablemente representen False's y True's). Me gustaría saber si en efecto estoy acertado y que representa cada uno de los tres argumentos de la función color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En realidad se acepta cualquier valor [**RGB**](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGB) para el color. Cada uno de los posibles argumentos define el valor para los tres canales que representan los  tres colores de luz primarios, el rojo (`R`), verde (`G`) y azul (`B`) respectivamente.

Lo que pasa es que, por defecto, se espera que definas el color de forma aritmética usando floats. En esta notación el valor para cada canal (Rojo-Verde-Azul) va de **0 a 1.0 con cualquier valor decimal intermedio posible** (0.2, 0.145, 0.8541, 0.9, etc).

En realidad, a [`color()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/turtle.html#turtle.color) se le pueden pasar los colores de cuatro formas distintas y ella se encarga de parsearlas cada una de forma correcta:

- **sRGB floats** (0-1.0)
- **HTML RGB hexadecimal** (0-FFFFFF)
- **HTML nombres naturales** ("Red", "Blue", "Fuchsia", etc)
- **sRGB decimal** (0-255)

Por defecto se pueden introducir los colores de las tres primeras formas. Indicar los valores RGB en floats es poco intuitivo ya que estamos acostumbrados a usar el rango 0-255 (valores posibles que podemos almacenar en un byte). Esto se puede cambiar usando el método [`turtle.colormode`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/turtle.html#turtle.colormode).

Dejo un ejemplo reproducible mostrando las tres posibilidades:

```
import turtle 

turtle.setup(600, 400)
wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.bgcolor("black")     # Por nombre

t = turtle.Pen()
t.shape("turtle")
t.penup()

t.color("Chartreuse")   # Por nombre
t.backward(100)
t.stamp()

t.color(0.8, 0.3, 0.1)  # RGB 0-1.0
t.forward(40)
t.stamp()

t.color("Crimson")      # Por nombre
t.forward(40)
t.stamp()

turtle.colormode(255)   # Cambiamos para usar rango 0-255
t.color(210, 100, 214)  #RGB 0-255
t.forward(40)
t.stamp()

t.color(255,0,255)    # RGB 0-255
t.forward(40)
t.stamp()

t.color("#FFD700")    # RGB hexadecimal
t.forward(40)
t.stamp()

turtle.done()
```

**Salida:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Puedes ver posibles nombres de colores, así como sus valores RGB usando una [tabla de colores HTML](https://www.w3schools.com/colors/colors_names.asp).